# How to set Window and Taskbar Icon with PyQT4 and PyInstaller?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I am developing an application with PyQT4 and Python 2.7. I am using PyInstaller to compile/build the application to an executable.

The issue I'm having is whenever I build the application using PyInstaller using its *--icon=icon.ico* (for example), it gives the application an icon. However, the taskbar icon and the window icon do not show.

When I do not use the parameter (*--icon*), and use the following lines instead, the application has no icon, yet the taskbar icon and window icon both have the correct icons.

```
app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/Images/icon.ico'))
LoginMainWindow.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(':/images/Images/icon.ico'))
```

If I combine both the parameter and those lines of code, the application has an icon, yet the taskbar icon and window icon do not show.

Comment: Nobody has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but let it help others with same problem. First of all, use `PyQt5`, `PyQt Designer`, `pyuic5` and `pyinstaller`. Use Designer to create your UI. In there, in Window options you can set window icon. You can use `.ico`, `.png`, `.jpg` and so on but use `.ico` format. After that save your `.ui` file from designer and use `pyuic5` to convert your `.ui` file to `.py` file. I used the following command `pyuic5 myui.ui --o=ui.py`. After this you need to go to `ui.py`, find `icon` and change relative path to absolute path. Then continue building your app. When you get to the step when you need to create `.exe` file use pyinstaller. I used the following command `pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --icon=icon.ico --name=appName app.py`. After building the `.exe` app you will find `dist` folder. Inside, there is your `.exe` app. Try and run it. There should be an icon in app window and taskbar. IMPORTANT: bare in mind that every time you change `.ui` file in designer and/or do a conversion you will lose the change you made before and you need to do it again. Hope this helps